# Is there any difference between Namespace::* and traditional *?

Tags: c++, pointers, namespaces, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

```
class C {
    public:
    int a;
    int f();
};

int C::f() { return 0; }




int main() {


    C c {1};

    int(C::*pmf)() = &C::f;
    // int(*pmf)() = &C::f; -> error can not convert int(*C::f)() to int(*f)().


}
```

Is there any difference between Namespace::* and * in ram or it is just checked by compiler? Is it syntactic sugar?

Comment: Are you asking if/why a member function pointer is different from a regular function pointer? There's no namespace in your code.

Comment: Pointers to (non-static) member functions (of classes/structs) are different from regular (free) function pointers because member functions use a hidden additional parameter (the `this` pointer) under the hood. Read also https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer

Answer (score 0):

Of course: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

> Non-static member functions have a hidden parameter that corresponds to the this pointer. The this pointer points to the instance data for the object.

The functions are physically not interchangable as members have an extra parameter - the object that you call it from. You cannot see it, but the compiler puts it in there. And when that object is missing, compiler obviously complains. This is not like C#, where every function is a member function, and some just happen to be static (fun fact: when passing a C# function to a third party, the object that it is attached to gets passed along with it to allow a valid call later. You may and may not be able to get away with emulating something similar here).